# Как сохранять файл через Blob в кодировке Windows-1251?

Tags: javascript, blob

Получаю файл в *input type="file"* (допустим files), читаю его через FileReader:

```
var reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsText(files[0], "CP1251")
reader.onload = function() {
  var content = reader.result
  var blob = new Blob([content], {
      type: "text/plain" // добавление ;charset=windows-1251 не помогает
  })
}
```

Затем я пытаюсь его превратить в blob чтобы создать ссылку на сайте:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

При скачивании файл формата UTF-8, а не Windows-1251, как ожидалось. Почему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672834/specifying-blob-encoding-in-google-chrome

Comment: И как в том примере сделать Windows-1251?